# Operators overloading in iterator class in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading

I'm trying to do a little program where I use an iterator for my own vector class. I need to overload `operator *()` to get current element from vector , `operator++()` to make current position +1 , `operator !=`, `operator <`, etc.

Here is my class where I tried to create iterator and overload one operator:

```cpp
template < typename T>
class MyIterator {
private:
    vectorV<T> & someName;
    int position;

public:
    MyIterator( vectorV<T> & rq)
            : someName( rq ), position()
    {}

    T & operator*()
    {
        return myRingQueue; //???
    }

};
```

Comment: There must be thousands of tutorials and examples on how to create iterators, all over the Internet. Not to mentions tons of books and tutorials and examples about operator overloading in general.

Comment: For a vector, an iterator is usually pretty simple, just a thin wrapper over a pointer that points to an element in the vector. *, +, ++ pretty much just fall through to the regular pointer operations.

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
T & operator*()
{
    return someName[position];
}
```